# uninitialized constant in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a rails app but i have this problem that i cannot solve. I'm trying setting  Notification but this is the error that occur about initialized constant but i have the class and i check if it is on singular and it is so i don't know why compare this. Please help me.

```
class GroupNotification < Noticed::Base
  # Add your delivery methods
  #
  deliver_by :database
end

class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  include Noticed::Model
  belongs_to :recipient, polymorphic: true
end


class Group < ApplicationRecord
    #statement che associa un group all'utente che lo crea      

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :members
    has_many :roles
    has_many :partecipation
    
    #has_noticed_notifications param_name: :group, model_name: "Notification"

    after_create_commit :notify_recipient

    has_many :notifications, as: :recipient, dependent: :destroy

    before_destroy :remove_partecipation, if: :has_partecipation?
    before_destroy :cleanup_notifications



  private

  def notify_recipient
    GroupNotification.with(group: self).deliver_later(self.user)
  end

  def cleanup_notifications
    notifications_as_group.destroy_all
  end
```

the problem is

```
NameError in GroupsController#create
uninitialized constant Group::GroupNotification
Extracted source (around line #130):
128
129
130
131
132
133
              

  def notify_recipient
    GroupNotification.with(group: self).deliver_later(self.user)
  end

  private
```

Comment: What file is the `GroupNotification` code defined in?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever this code is called, it seems like it's in the `Group` module, so when you reference `GroupNotification` ruby assumes you mean relative to the current module "you're in" (`Group`).

You can probably fix it by replacing `GroupNotification` with `::GroupNotification`.

I also suspect you did not paste all relevant code because the output says

```
NameError in GroupsController#create
```

but in your examples, the only place `GroupController` is referenced is in the `Group` model.

Comment: thank you very much it was a problem like you suggested, i resolved changing notify_recipient